# How to delete the cell while clicking the delete button in mvvm

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, mvvm

I have listed the data in `UITableview`. So i got the output .The output is list of the names.

I have done in mvvm.Now i need to delete the cell while clicking the delete button and need to update the tableview.

**My ModelView:-**

```
class ViewModel: NSObject {
    var datasourceModel:DataSourceModel

    init(withdatasource  newDatasourceModel: DataSourceModel) {
        datasourceModel = newDatasourceModel
    }

    func datafordisplay(atindex indexPath: IndexPath) -> Model{
        return  datasourceModel.dataListArray![indexPath.row]
    }

    func numberOfRowsInSection(section:Int) -> Int {
        return (datasourceModel.dataListArray?.count)!
    }
}
```

**my DataSource Model Class:-**

```
class DataSourceModel: NSObject {
    var dataListArray:Array<Model>? = []

    init(array :Array<[String:Any]>?) {
        super.init()
        var newArray:Array<[String:Any]> = []
        if array == nil {
            newArray = self.getJsonDataStored22()
        }
        else {
            newArray = array!
        }

        var datalist:Array<Model> = []
        for dict in newArray {
            let model = Model(dictionary: dict)
            datalist.append(model!)
        }
        self.dataListArray = datalist
    }
}

typealias dummyDataSource22 =  DataSourceModel
extension dummyDataSource22 {
    func getJsonDataStored22() ->Array<Dictionary<String,String>>{
            let jsonArray = [["name":"Dosa Fest"],["name":"Organic Vegan Fest"],["name":"Food Of Life Time"],["name":"Tea Time"],["name":"Dosa Fest"],["name":"Organic Vegan Fest"],["name":"Food Of Life Time"],["name":"Tea Time"]] as Array<Dictionary<String,String>>
            return jsonArray
    }
}
```

**And my UIViewcontroller:-**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return chartViewModel.numberOfRowsInSection(section: section)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let identifier = "cell"
    var cell:ChartCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? ChartCell

    if cell == nil {
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ChartCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? ChartCell
    }

    cell.setEventData(charts: chartViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath))
    return cell
}
```

**MY UITableviewcell:-**

```
 @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!

     override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    func setEventData(charts:Model) {
        self.name.text = charts.restaurantname
    }
```

So now how to do the delete method while clicking the delete button .What all code should added in `ModelView` and `viewController`

Comment: hOW TO DELETE THE CELL IN mvvm method

Comment: If you use mvvm, you should send ui event like delete cell to your viewModel. viewModel change itself and send notification. then view(viewController) respond to it and change the UI.

Comment: @SolaWing how to do

Comment: @SolaWing what function should code in view model and viewcontroller

Comment: CAN ANY one solve the problem

Answer (score 3):

Normally, In MVVM, all UI related logic should be written in ViewModel, View or ViewController only need to show the UI according to ViewModel, and sent UI Event to ViewModel. when ViewModel changes, it send event or notification, so View can respond and change. this is called bind. Similarly, viewModel should bind to Model too.

In your case, ViewModel should have a delete method, like this

```
func delete(atIndex indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // model should declare modify method and viewModel should call it and observe changes too. here directly modify it for simplicity
    // you may also need to check input parameter is valid

    // now input is valid, do the change
    datasourceModel.dataListArray!.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    // and then fire a notification
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "DeleteAtRow"), object: self, userInfo: ["indexPath" : indexPath])
}
```

so view can pass event to it

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        // pass delete cell event to viewModel
        chartViewModel.delete(atIndex: indexPath)
    }
}
```

view also need to bind the changes

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(viewModelDeleteRows(n:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "DeleteAtRow"), object: chartViewModel)
}

@objc func viewModelDeleteRows(n: NSNotification) {
    if let i = n.userInfo?["indexPath"] as? IndexPath {
        // respond to viewModel changes and sync UI
        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [i], with: .automatic)
    }
}
```

Additionally, you can pass cell delete event to it's controller, then controller can pass to viewModel

```
var deleteCell : ((ChartCell) -> Void)?
@IBAction func clickDeleteButton(sender: UIButton) {
    deleteCell?(self)
}
```

and configure cell

```
cell.deleteCell = {[weak self] in
        if let i = self?.tableView.indexPath(for: $0) {
            self?.chartViewModel.delete(atIndex: i)
        }
}
```

Comment: this is working....thanks a lot....but  i have a button on the tableviewcell.So while clicking that delete button it should delete .So what changes should make

Comment: viewController can add a callback to the cell's button, then when button click, it can find the indexPath and call viewModel's method.

Comment: i have given the button outlet in the tableviewcell.so did i need to give action in the tableviewcell class.If so,how to do

Comment: cell can declare a block as callback, then in cell's button click method, call the block

Comment: hi,can u give the code to do call the block on the cell's click method

Comment: can solve the problem.i need while clicking on the custom  delete button.Not while swiping the cell

Comment: @robbieroberts I have updated answer to pass cell delete event to viewController

Comment: WHERE should this code need to give :-var deleteCell : ((ChartCell) -> Void)?
@IBAction func clickDeleteButton(sender: UIButton) {
    deleteCell?(self)
}

Comment: @robbieroberts of course in cell, IBAction is the xib callback of your cell